# Substracting two normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

I was wondering if we have two normal distributions of X,Y~N(0,1), why is then X-2Y~N(0,5)? I understand the mean of the X-2Y distribution, but why is the variance 5?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+sum+normal+independent.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we can do
 $$Var(X-2Y) = Var(X)+Var(2Y)=Var(X)+4 Var(Y) = 1 +4(1) = 5.$$